# Как изменить ссылку с помощью .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

http://site/wp-content/uploads/pdf.php
преобразовать в http://site/pdf
Как можно такое реализовать??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам необходимо, чтобы запрос `/pdf` обрабатывался скриптом `/wp-content/uploads/pdf.php`?

Тогда так:

```
RewriteRule ^pdf /wp-content/uploads/pdf.php [L,QSA]
```